# How pass data from parent to child in NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

i wonder how passing some string or dynamic data from parent to child in NuxtJs

how i tried it and not worked:

it's my parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
     <ChildComponent :someData="Some String" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import ChildComponent from "~/components/childComponent.vue";

export default {
 components: {
    ChildComponent,
  },
}
</script>
```

and here is my ChildComponent

```
<template>

  <div>
    {{someData}}
  </div>

</template>

<script>

export default {
 name:"ChildComponent",
 props: {
   someData: String
 }
}
</script>
```

and this method nothing rendered in ChildComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to bind if you are passing values directly, ie, no need of semicolon.

```
<ChildComponent someData="Some String" />
```

You only need to bind if you are passing data.

```
<template>
  <div>
     <ChildComponent :someData="localData" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import ChildComponent from "~/components/childComponent.vue";

export default {
 components: {
    ChildComponent,
  },
  data(){
    return {
      localData: "Some String"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```